# iOS Storyboard AutoLayout how to place UIView at the bottom in the both of 3.5" and 4" screens?

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

I want to place black UIView at the bottom in the both of 3.5" and 4" screens using AutoLayout.
I added bottom constraints on the black UIView, but the view was always hidden in 3.5" screen.
I will never use AutoLayout in next project, but in current project, how can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Following is parent view's constraints.

[image]

Comment: What are the constraints on the superview? Is it being resized properly or is it too high...

Comment: @Wain. I've just added parent view's constraints diagram. Please consider it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: Select black view press add new constraint button check height and click only buttom constraint and add these two. After that press add missing constraints button. It should solve your issue.

Comment: Great. I added Height constraint to black view, and it  solved the problem.

Comment: @BoranA : is it possible for you to look at my problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021077/what-is-the-need-to-resize-subviews-programatically-when-using-storybaords) as it is more or less similar.

Comment: @BalramTiwari Sorry, I wasn't online. I've just looked to your question and this answer is also suitable for your problem. One more thing, sooner or later you will need to work with autolayouts, better learn asap :)

Comment: @BoranA : Yes, I have taken hint from your answer as well as the selected one & I can confirm that, I have learned a bit of it. I got my problem fixed & will try to use auto layout going forward. A +vote to you too.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of things it is the constraints on the superview that are the issue. This looks to result in the superview being too high on a 3.5 screen.

Check the superview constraints and ensure that:

1. The height is not pinned
2. The top and bottom of the view are pinned to appropriate things

Check the 'document outline' and see if it lists any layout issues - correct them. Each view needs to tell the layouting system where is should be placed and how big it should be.

p.s. you should use auto-layout in your future projects

Comment: I have checked the superview constraints. The height is not pinned, but how the top and bottom of the view can be pinned to appropriate things? I think it has already all possible constraints.

Comment: You are pinning the sides to `View` - what is that. The superview of the black view is what (a container)? Why is the black view bottom pinned to the layout guide? The superview should be pinned to that (top and bottom probably) and the black pinned to the superview.