# What is the need to resize subviews programmatically when using storyboards?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, autolayout

I am well versed with custom views. Today I have started using storyboards & I am not able to convince myself on the usage of storyboard.

Problem: 
 - I have set up by View Controller in storyboard.
 - Running on simulator 4 inch, I am good to Go with the layouts of Views. 
 - Running on simulator 3.5 inch, I am upset, as my view is partially visible.

Here are screen shots.

- My SotryBaord (Look at the "Delete User" Button).

  [image]
- Delete User button frame:

  [image]
- Running on Simulator 4 inch

  [image]
- **Running on Simulator 4 inch** (I have problem)

  [image]

**how do I get the frame adjusted with layouts so that it runs clear in both size iPhones. My delete user button should not go off the screen.**

Comment: have you setup autolayout?

Comment: yes, on the name of autoLayout, I have the checkbox `Use AutoLaout` selected.

Comment: You might have to learn autolayout. This is a very good tutorial for autolayout. http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: Just pin the distance between your button and the bottom of your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mate, Auto layout is somewhat complex, you need to master it while giving lot of time, but if you want to finish it in minutes, just uncheck the auto-layout, select every UI element and set its auto-resizing like this [image].

You can change the auto-layout differently, and can see the changes by just tapping this button [image]

Hope this will help and save time.

Answer (score 1):

Very good question. I had ran into exactly same issues as you have with every single app of mine when I upgraded them to support iphone 5 screen size.

What I ended up doing was disable autolayout but I still use story board to place all my buttons, views, images etc. I make sure that I am using 3.5in in my storyboard while placing all the items. I then connect those UILabel or UIButton etc to an IBoutLet and then in my ViewDidLoad I check to see if its iphone 4 vs iPhone 5 and re position all the buttons accordingly.

for example.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
            if(result.height == 480)
            {
                // iPhone Classic

            }
            if(result.height == 568)
            {
                // iPhone 5 this is the offset I am using
                int yInt = 50;

                [blurSlider setFrame:CGRectMake(31, 406+yInt, 271, 34)];
                [alphaSlider setFrame:CGRectMake(31, 447+yInt, 271, 34)];

                [blurLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(33, 392+yInt, 71, 24)];
                [alphaLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(33, 436+yInt, 71, 24)];
            }
        }
}
```

Could I have done all the coding without ever using story board? of course I could have but I find the visual aspect of story board appealing and seeing exactly where everything fits on the screen.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think this is much like a custom view approcah & I am well versed with this. Interestingly I wanted to know the benifit of using storyboards auto layout. Thanks for the help.